# Get the sign of a number in C# without conditional statement

Tags: c#, r

Just out of curiosity, is there a way to get the sign of a number, any kind (but obviously a signed type), not just integer using some bitwise/masking, or other kind of, operation?
That is without using any conditional statement or calling the Math.Sign() function.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I recognize it was a misleading question. What I had in mind more likely something like: "get the same output of the Math.Sign() or, simplifying get 0 if x <= 0, 1 otherwise".

**EDIT #2**: to all those asking for code, I didn't have any in mind when I posted the question, but here's an example I came up with, just to give a context of a possible application:

```
x = (x < 0) ? 0 : x;
```

Having the sign into a variable could lead to:

```
x = sign * x; //where sign = 0 for x <= 0, otherwise sign = 1;
```

The aim would be to achieve the same result as the above :)

### **EDIT #3**: FOUND IT! :D

```
// THIS IS NOT MEANT TO BE PLAIN C#!
// Returns 0 if x <= 0, 1 otherwise.
int SignOf(x)
{
    return (1+x-(x+1)%x)/x;
}
```

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: What have you tried, did you try looking up how numeric types are stored in memory? Did you try to get the bytes and performing bitwise operations to get the sign bit? Why don't you want Math.Sign?

Comment: "Method X does exactly what I want. How can I achieve this without calling method X?" Questions like that are pretty pointless without explaining *why* you don't want to call method X...

Comment: Withoud any conditional statement it is impossible to detect if number i signed or unsigned.

Comment: Even if you succeed in doing any bitwise operation you still would have to do a conditional statement somehow. Why would you try to avoid them?

Comment: @JonSkeet it was out of curiosity, not for practical application, unless you can find one. As a matter of fact I use the Math.Sign().

Comment: @CodeCaster Indeed I tried and I failed, otherwise I wouldn't post a question here :)

Comment: @Jusanne Actually that depend on what you're gonna use the result for. Let's say its for some kind of assignment like this:
`x = (x < 0) ? 0 : x;`
In this case the bit sign could be useful and no conditional statement would be required.

Comment: "How to" is generally too broad, so if you want your code fixed, show your code.

Comment: @ANVerona the operator ?: is a conditional statement. Even if you can get the information in any way you'll have to test that result in a way (being a if / the ?: operator / any other way). The only alternative is having the result but never using it (but that wouldn't be much productive)

Comment: @Jusanne the aim of my question is exactly to avoid the '?' operator. The assigment I posted was to give you an idea of where having the operation to get the sign of a number could be usefull. :)

Comment: @Jusanne Found the result! Thx anyway for your help :)

Comment: @CodeCaster Found the result! Thx anyway for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to get the sign of a number (any kind, not just integer)

Not for any number type, no. For an integer, you can test the most significant bit: if it's 1, the number is negative. You could theoretically do the same with a floating point number, but bitwise operators don't work on `float` or `double`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that's what I found out as well, but isn't there a way to circumvent that? I was looking for that :)

Comment: @ANVerona, not that I know of. What's wrong with Math.Sign?

Comment: nothing! Just wanted to know if there was another method using just arithmetic and bit logic. :)

Comment: Found the result! Thx anyway for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a "zero safe" solution that works for all value types (int, float, double, decimal...etc):

```
int sign = (value.GetHashCode() >> 31) + 1;
```

Output: 1 = 1, -1 = 0, 0.5 = 1, -0.5 = 0, 0 = 1

It's also roughly 10% cheaper than `(1+x-(x+1)%x)/x;` in C#. Additionally if "value" is an integer, you can drop the GetHashCode() function call in which case `(1+x-(x+1)%x)/x;` is 127% more expensive (`(value >> 31) + 1;` is 56% cheaper).

Since 0 is positive it is illogical for a result of 1 for positive numbers & a result of 0 for 0. If you could parametrise -0 you would get an output of 0.

I understand that GetHashCode() is a function call, but the inner workings of the function in the C# language implementation is entirely "arithmetic". Basically the GetHashCode() function reads the memory section, that stores your float type, as an integer type:

```
*((int*)&singleValue)
```

How the GetHashCode function works (best source I could find quickly) - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3c3fde60-1b4a-449f-afdc-fe5bba8fece3/hash-code-of-floats?forum=netfxbcl

If you want the output value to be 1 with the same sign as the input, use:

```
int sign = ((float.GetHashCode() >> 31) * 2) + 1;
```

The above floating-point method is roughly 39% cheaper than `System.Math.Sign(float)` (`System.Math.Sign(float)` is roughly 65% more expensive). Where `System.Math.Sign(float)` throws an exception for float.NaN, `((float.NaN.GetHashCode() >> 31) * 2) + 1;` does not and will return -1 instead of crashing.

or for integers:

```
int sign = ((int >> 31) * 2) + 1;
```

The above integer method is roughly 56% cheaper than `System.Math.Sign(int)` (`System.Math.Sign(int)` is roughly 125% more expensive).

**Edit 1:**

For **integer** value types that are smaller, or larger, than 32-bit, substitute their bit count - 1 wherever you see the value literal "31" used above. For example:

```
int sign = ((short >> 15) * 2) + 1;
```

(note that right-shifting a low order value type (32 bits or less) in C# always returns a 32 bit integer)

or

```
long sign = ((long >> 63) * 2) + 1;
```

**Edit 2:**

For the double & decimal value types, the built-in C# GetHashCode function can only return a 32-bit value type. This means that there aren't enough bits to hold those value types' possible negative & positive values. Therefore, a large portion of negative values (passed to the GetHashCode function) return positive integers, and a vast portion of positive values return negative integers, breaking this approach.

In fact, there is no efficient way to use this approach for the decimal value type as there is no built-in 128 bit integer in C# (BigInteger could be used, but it would be a programming intensive approach & highly inefficient compared to a simple if statement). As for the 64 bit double value type, an efficient solution still exists but you'll have to enable the 'unsafe' command line option in your C# compiler. Once 'unsafe' code is enabled, substitute the GetHashCode function with this code: `*((long*)&doubleValue)`. Making the final algorithm for doubles look like this:

```
unsafe{
...
long sign = (*((long*)&doubleValue) >> 63) + 1;
...}
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work for `double`, in my testing.   Apart from that, it's a nice solution

Comment: @radfast, you're quite right. This solution will only work for 32-bit value types. For double, use the value literal "63" instead of "31"; likewise, decimal would be "127" instead of "31". Thanks for pointing that ambiguity out.

Comment: Buuut ... `.GetHashCode()` always returns an integer, even for 64-bit or larger value types.  And if `A` is an integer, `A >> 63` at bytecode level will be encoded as `A >> 31`, it applies a modulo 32 operation at bytecode level.  So I don't see the mechanism.  It can only work if `.GetHashCode()` for a double returns an int with the sign bit in bit 31, and I don't know whether or not it does ....    `(((float)value).GetHashCode() >> 31) + 1;` would work for doubles but the performance cost of the type conversion might exceed the benefits of this technique

Comment: Good point, I just double checked, and the built in C# hash code function for doubles does indeed generate a 32 bit integer. Weird, for this specific case it would be more intuitive if it generated a long but I'm pretty sure what we're doing here is outside the scope what hash codes are actually used for; indexing hash tables and whatnot. Also, I think you're right that the extra truncation conversion would be problematic for performance. The best solution, then, is to change the compiler command line option for unsafe code, then you could write `*((long*)&double)` in place of `.GetHashCode()`

Comment: Also, this specific approach does not work at all for decimal value types (see "Edit 2" in the answer). I was wrong in my comment before when I said, "...decimal would be '127' instead..."

Comment: Oh yea, the algorithm does in fact work for the 64 bit long value type. The right-shift operation for the 64 bit long value type returns a long; not an int. You are also right in saying that if A is a 32 bit integer, `A >> 63` is equivalent to `A >> 31`. In fact, in that scenario, `A >> 1000000` is also equivalent to `A >> 31`. But, if A is a 64 bit long, `(A >> 63) + 1` will work just fine and is **not** equivalent to `A >> 31`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of number value type you are targeting.

For *signed* [Integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29) C# and most computer systems use the so called [Ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) representation.

That means the sign is stored in the first bit of the value.

So you can *extract* the sign like this:

```
Int16 number = -2;
Int16 sign = (number & Int16.MinValue) >> 16;
Boolean isNegative = Convert.ToBoolean(sign);
```

Note that up until now we have not used any conditional operator (explicitly anyways)

But: **You** still don't know whether the number has a sign or not.

The logical equivalent of your question: "How do I know, **if** my number is negative?" explicitly requires the usage of a conditional operator as the question is, after all *conditional*.

So you won't be able to dodge:

```
if(isNegative) 
     doThis();
else
     doThat();
```

Answer (score -1):

to just get the sign, you can avoid conditional operators as you will see below in Sign extension of int32 struct. however to get the name I dont think you can avoid conditional operator

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(0.Sign()); 
        Console.WriteLine(0.SignName());

        Console.WriteLine(12.Sign());
        Console.WriteLine(12.SignName());

        Console.WriteLine((-15).Sign());
        Console.WriteLine((-15).SignName());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class extensions
{
    public static string Sign(this int signedNumber)
    {
        return (signedNumber.ToString("+00;-00").Substring(0, 1));
    }

    public static string SignName(this int signedNumber)
    {
        return (signedNumber.ToString("+00;-00").Substring(0, 1)=="+"?"positive":"negative");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Krishna. But what about avoiding a function call as well, and use just some plain "arithmetic". I quoted that because I imagine some bitwise masking and/or other bit operation are required.

:)

Comment: Found the result! Thx anyway for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

`if x==0` you will have a `divby0 exception` with this code you posted:

```
int SignOf(x) {
    return (1+x-(x+1)%x)/x; }
```