# Round a number without using if statement

Tags: c#, math, optimization

This is a matter of efficiency; I'm doing a lot of rounding in a tight loop and want to avoid conditional branching. I'm rounding to whole numbers.

The following numbers on the left should round to the numbers on the right:

1.2 -> 1.0, 1.5 -> 2.0, -1.2 -> -1.0, -1.5 -> -2.0

I have made a simple function which can round **positive numbers** given my above constraints.

```
  public static float RoundFast(float num)
  {
    return (int)(num + 0.5f);
  }
```

However, this will not produce desired results if `num` is negative. I was thinking about multiplying the `0.5f` with the sign of `num`, however `Math.Sign` uses conditional branching from what I understand. I cannot bitshift a float in C# and am unaware of any way other to obtain the sign from the float without using branching.

How can I make this support rounding negative numbers as well?

Comment: Unless you check the generated assembly code (including that of the library calls), you cannot know if conditional branches enter into play or not.

Comment: You've listed 1.5 -> 2.0, but what about other halves? Should 0.5 go to 0 or to 1?

Comment: Can you explain _why_ exactly you're writing rounding code like this instead of using `Math.Round`?

Comment: @MarnixvanValen: he said it: this is a matter of efficiency.

Comment: So let's change the question. Why effiency is really a matter here? Is it for academic purposes? Are you dealing with some kind of software where it really does make a difference? I think we could give better answers depending on the underlying subject, or not at all, but I'm interested in the answer anyway.

Comment: Will you accept answers based on dll-importing from a native library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this with at least one `if` to determine whether the number is positive or negative.

If you want your own function, you can use this:

```
return num >= 0 ? (int)(num + 0.5f) : (int)(num - 0.5f);
```

...another possibility would be:

```
var a = Math.Abs(num);
var b = a / num; // "b" will be -1 for negative numbers and 1 for positive...
return (int)((a + 0.5f) * b);
```

...but still `Math.Abs` uses `if statements` internally. Also this adds an extra division and multiplication, and the first example uses only one `if` statement, which I believe it has a better performance.

Or you can use the built-in `Math.Round()` method, specifying a `MidpointRounding`:

```
Math.Round(1.2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // 1
Math.Round(1.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // 2
Math.Round(-1.2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // -1
Math.Round(-1.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // -2
```

---

### Tests with custom method

I ran a test and [here is the C# fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/esNxHL), and below it's the method:

```
public static void Main()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine(Round(1.2));
        Console.WriteLine(Round(1.5));
        Console.WriteLine(Round(-1.2));
        Console.WriteLine(Round(-1.5));
    }
}

public static int Round(double num)
{
    return num >= 0 ? (int)(num + 0.5f) : (int)(num - 0.5f);
}
```

Results:

```
Compile:    0.301s
Execute:    0.012s~0.047s
Memory: 406.73kb~1.68Mb
CPU:    0.016s~0.078s
```

### Tests with Math.Round

I also tested with `Math.Round` and [here is the Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/usvHQO), and the method:

```
public static void Main()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1.2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(-1.2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(-1.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Compile:    0.216s
Execute:    0.016s~0.031s
Memory: 494.41kb~1.68Mb
CPU:    0.062s
```

---

### Conclusion

Both methods are using 4 use cases (two positives, two negatives), and executing the four 2.147.483.647 times, which is the `int.MaxValue`.

The difference between both methods being executed almost ten billion times in a row isn't that much, the custom method is a bit faster than `Math.Round`. I'd go for `Math.Round` anyway, but you can make your choice.

Comment: How do you know if this is branchless ??? Actually, as there is a rounding policy argument which will be taken into account by the function, this is certainly a less efficient approach. Calling an opaque function is certainly not the way.

Comment: @YvesDaoust what do you mean by being branchless?

Comment: Precisely what the OP wants: no conditional branches.

Comment: "this is the best way to achieve what you want": no, it's not.

Comment: @YvesDaoust do you think people should just not use `Math.Round()`? Or not at least for what OP wants? I still don't understand...

Comment: The quality criterion of the OP is performance, not convenience. Hence Round is not the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I've run a bunch of the answers through BenchmarkDotNet tests. The full code of the tests is in this in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/alanta/944c5d3960a19ca48e6817c3f4c125f6).

The test generates 100.000 pseudo-random floats between -2.5 and 2.5 and converts them to `int` in various ways.

The results are all within the same order of magnitude so I'd say for pretty much all common cases sticking to the platform standard `Math.Round` is perfectly ok.

When looking for the best performance, @Yves Daoust's code is the winner:

```
        Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
 ------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|
         Round | 5.539 ms | 0.0545 ms | 0.0483 ms | Math.Round
    AddAndCast | 1.678 ms | 0.0356 ms | 0.1045 ms | OPs original code
   AddAndCast2 | 2.422 ms | 0.0478 ms | 0.0701 ms | Yves Daoust's code
     RoundFast | 4.494 ms | 0.0310 ms | 0.0274 ms | 
  ConvertToInt | 3.890 ms | 0.0279 ms | 0.0233 ms | Convert.ToInt32
```

A note on the code; yes, I used Linq to loop over the data but since I used the same linq statement in all samples I think it's safe to assume that it doesn't impact the result.
I've executed this on my laptop in a .Net 4.6.1 console application built in Release configuration.

**Update**

I've added @harolds native code as requested in the comments end replaced the Linq code with a for-loop.

```
        Method |        Mean |      Error |     StdDev |
 ------------- |------------:|-----------:|-----------:|
         Round | 4,085.99 us | 78.7908 us | 77.3831 us |
    AddAndCast |   151.86 us |  2.9784 us |  2.9252 us |
   AddAndCast2 |   774.20 us | 12.8013 us | 11.9743 us |
     RoundFast | 3,043.38 us | 52.9597 us | 49.5386 us |
  ConvertToInt | 2,567.69 us | 44.3540 us | 41.4887 us |
        Native |    26.20 us |  0.4291 us |  0.4014 us |
```

Looks like Linq had a much bigger impact (around 1.5 ms) than I expected. I suspect the compiler can optimize the for loop much better but I'd love to hear from a more knowledgeable person about this.

The code for this test run is in [another gist](https://gist.github.com/alanta/fe6d10abcad5217deff9a25b32ddb172).

Comment: Interestingly, my code was meant to be fast only if the compiler translated to conditional instructions. But it does not ! I have added a more hacky code which is branchless, but I don't expect it to be faster because of overhead.

Comment: Appreciate the effort saved me some time. Cheers.

Comment: Could you test mine too, so we have the data all from the same machine?

Comment: @harold there ya go :)

Comment: I didn't expect that much linq overhead either, turns out it's really barely optimized, unlike `foreach` over an array. `ToArray` goes via `Buffer`, but then *actually* (not just notionally) calls `MoveNext` of the iterator (instance of `WhereSelectArrayIterator`), and then it *actually calls* the delegate instead of inlining it. A weird amount of overhead for something so simple.

Answer (score 2):

It is not impossible that the statement below be implemented with conditional assignments, hence be branchless. But you need to check the generated assembly:

```
return num >= 0 ? (int)(num + 0.5f) : (int)(num - 0.5f);
```

---

At your own risk, you can also hack into the IEEE float representation and replace all bits but the sign by the FP representation of `0.5f`.

- Emulate a union type:

  ```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
  struct Union { [FieldOffset(0)] public float x; [FieldOffset(0)] public int i; };
  ```
- Tweak the bits

  ```
  Union U;
  U.i = 0;

  U.x= x;
  U.i = 1056964608 | (-2147483648 & U.i); // Transfer the sign bit to 0.5f
  int i = (int)(x + U.x);
  ```

Note that the assignment `U.i= 0` is added only to please the compiler (believing in an unassigned field). When benchmarking, it should be done once for all.

Comment: This does not compile.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma: typo fixed. In any case, assembly code should be looked at, with in the desired optimization level.

Comment: There is no `int(expr)` operator. I suppose you mean `(int) (num + 0.5f)` instead.

Comment: That cast syntax doesn't work in C# either, but minor syntax problems aside, the disassembly I'm seeing is [this](https://pastebin.com/ppe7MgGv). So, I agree that it could have been compiled cleverly but (as all too often) the .NET JIT engine disappointed.

Comment: Sorry, I have been using C++ syntax.

Comment: @Harold: this compile is using SSE opcodes. Scalar code might be better.

Comment: @Harold: I know it's scalar but the generated code uses vector instructions (even when forcing 32 bits), which don't really support conditional assignment.

Comment: @YvesDaoust is allows masking, which is even more powerful in a way. Emulating cmov in SSE is easy, and there are more tricks.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow native imports, you can write this in a separate C++ project:

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void roundAll(int len, float* data)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < len - 3; i += 4)
        {
            __m128 d = _mm_loadu_ps(data + i);
            d = _mm_round_ps(d, _MM_FROUND_TO_NEAREST_INT | _MM_FROUND_NO_EXC);
            _mm_storeu_ps(data + i, d);
        }
        for (; i < len; i++)
        {
            __m128 d = _mm_load_ss(data + i);
            d = _mm_round_ss(d, d, _MM_FROUND_TO_NEAREST_INT | _MM_FROUND_NO_EXC);
            _mm_store_ss(data + i, d);
        }
    }
}
```

Import it like this:

```
[DllImport("nativeFunctions.dll")] // or however you call your dll
static extern void roundAll(int len, float[] data);
```

In my tests it was about 14 times as fast as doing it in C# using the simple
`data[i] = (float)Math.Round(data[i])` in a for loop, but your results will depend on the size of the array, which .NET version your use, and whether it's making 32bit code or 64bit code.

Comment: I will have to test your solution then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should be without any conditional branches:

```
public static float RoundFast(float num)
{
    return (int) (num + 0.5f * (-1 + 2 *(1 + num - (num + 1) % num) / num));
}
```

Credits for the *sign detection* part go to: [Get the sign of a number in C# without conditional statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560366/get-the-sign-of-a-number-in-c-sharp-without-conditional-statement)

[.NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uczByi)

Comment: Yep, but it uses a modulo and a division, which are much worse :)

Comment: @YvesDaoust The OP explicitly states that *wants to avoid conditional branching*. While you may be right, he did not mention other limitations.

Comment: Don't be bad faith. He stated "this is a matter of efficiency" in the first place, which is a good reason to avoid conditional branches. But float divisions are terribly slower.

Comment: @YvesDaoust We may stay here and argue forever on what the OP "intended", but the question is not *"What is the fastest way for rounding a number?"* but simply *"Round a number without using if statement"*. This responds to the question. Performance considerations are secondary.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma While I appreciate your effort and I think your solution is interesting, I do like it when people try to read into the spirit of the question. Clearly my title wasn't perfectly aligned with my intentions, apologies for that. I think it's reasonable to deduce that I am trying to find the *fastest* solution. I wasn't aware at the time of posting that float division is more expensive than conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static float RoundFast(float num)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32( num );
}
```

Comment: You should perhaps cite or link https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ffdk7eyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, "value, rounded to the nearest 32-bit signed integer. "

Comment: Can you guarantee that this is branchless ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust yup, its ready to go kind of sample, tested for results with your sample data.